# How to fire up function after two clicks in item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, click

i use an roundabout script for my project menu. I have some action after menu items click. I want to fire this actions/function after second click at this selected item. Can you help my how to do this?

This is start of my function:

```
$('.main_content ul li').bind({click: function(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to manually cancel the first click:

```
$('.main_content ul li').click(function() {

    if(!$(this).data('clicked-once')) {
        $(this).data('clicked-once', true);
        return; // cancel first execution
    }

    // handler body here

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhGCe/)

Another, perhaps neater, would be to use the `one` method for binding the listener:

```
$('.main_content ul li').one('click', function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
      // handler body here
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg46q/)

Of course, if it is an actual double click you're trying to listen to, you should use the `dblclick` event as Tats_innit suggests. That is, if you only want to fire an event upon two clicks in close succession. With doubleclick, three quick clicks would fire the function only once, and with the solutions above, it would fire twice. With doubleclick, two clicks with some delay between them would not cause the function to fire at all, and the seolutions above would cause it to fire once.

Comment: nice, thx man it's work fine and corectly, chears and vodka shot for you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

API: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Bind an event handler to the "dblclick" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Hope it help your cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('.main_content ul li').dblclick( function(){

});
```

Comment: doubleclick is not strictly the same as two clicks, though.

Comment: Indeed @DavidHedlund I agree bruv! `:)` hows you/life? it seems OP is looking for dblclick instead of any class based solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit* Ignore this and use Tats_innit's answer. I was shamefully unaware of the dblclick feature of jQuery.

```
(function(){
    var state = false;
    $('.main_content ul li').click(function(){
        if( state === false ) state = true;
        if( state ){
            state = false;
            //do other stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery's [toggle event helper](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), and bind only one function. Something in the line:

```
function iWantThis2bCalled()
{
}

$("#someId").toggle(function(){}, iWantThis2bCalled);
```

Comment: Yo bruv I reckon you are taking it a notch up `:)` might or might not be right worth explaining a bit `:)`

Comment: This doesn't prevent just the first click though, but every second click. Five clicks = 2 executions of `iWantThis2bCalled`.